# Как удалить символ или очистить все в файле на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Я делал игру RUNNER на Python и хотел сделать функцию сохранения, но не знаю как очистить символ или несколько, также как очистить все. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А что такое "Очистить символ" ? пробел на его место поставить или как ? Просто если удалить, то придется прочитать и переписать полностью все, что идет после него. А очистить все просто, если вы открываете файл в режиме 'w' то он усекается до нулевой длины. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) . Или воспользуйтесь truncate для обрезания до нужной длины https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/metody-fajlovogo-obekta-potoka-python/metod-file-truncate/

Comment: Очистить символ я имел ввиду удалить его.

Answer (score 2):

Удалить символ/слово/предложение можно через функцию `open()` и метод `replace()`.

```py
with open('example.txt', mode='r') as file:
    text = file.read()
    with open('example.txt', mode='w') as file2:
        file2.write(text.replace(old='тут символ/слово/предложение', new=''))
```

Очистить файл можно так:

```py
file = open('example.txt', mode='w')
file.close()
```

[Подробнее про open()](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-open/)

[Подробнее про replace()](https://pythonstart.ru/string/replace-python)